# for loop iteration_expression value doesn't increment on loop exit

Tags: c++, for-loop

I have code which needs the value of my loop counter after the scope exit. As such, I initialize `i` outside the loop.

```
size_t i;
for (i = 0; i < size / 16 * 16; i += 16) {
    // Magical unicorns.
}
```

However, I was surprised to see the value of `i` will be the last valid value, not the one that caused the loop exit.

For example, if I have a `size` of 15, `i` will be 0 (and not 16 as I would have expected). If I have a size of 17, `i` will be 16 (not 32).

I can't find information on cppreference regarding this behaviour of the `iteration_expression`. Is this standard behaviour, or is it a clang thing?

Comment: It's an integer division thing

Comment: Tell me more...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For example, if I have a size of 15, i will be 0 (and not 16 as I would have expected). If I have a size of 17, i will be 16 (not 32).

That isn’t how integer division works in c

15 / 16 = 0

And 0 times anything is 0... so `i` isn’t less than 0.. no loop increment, no loop.

Answer (score 0):

If `size` is `15`, `size / 16 * 16` evaluates to `0` because `size / 16` evaluates to `0` due to integer division.

If `size` is `17`, `size / 16 * 16` evaluates to `16` because `size / 16` evaluates to `1`.

Use `i < size / 16.0 * 16` if you want floating point division.  Note that the first `16` is changed to `16.0`, making it a `double` instead of an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Use of `i < size / 16 * 16;` suffers from the problem caused by integer division but more importantly, I don't think you need it at all. Since you are using `i += 16`, all you need is:

```
size_t i;
for (i = 0; i < size; i += 16) {
    // Magical unicorns.
}
```

If you must use that logic, it will be simpler to use:

```
size_t i;
for (i = 0; i*16 < size; i += 16) {
    // Magical unicorns.
}
```

Comment: No I need it, I was just having some sort of aneurism -.-